# Trouble getting fragment returning to previous fragment correctly

Tags: android

***Answered:*** I had a searchview in Fragment A that still had focus behind Fragment B, so the first backpress was clearing that focus, letting the second backpress do what I thought it should. Thank you for your help, I apologize the information I posted originally wasn't sufficient in helping me find a solution to my problem.

**Problem**
I'm running into an issue where when I add and commit a new fragment, it requires two back button presses to return to the previous view.

**Note**: this only occurs on the first item you select, once you succesfully back out to the fragment containing the listview and select the object again or a new object it only requires you press the back button once.

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long arg3) {
            final Obj item = (obj) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putParcelable("obj", item);
            Fragment fragment = new ObjFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(b);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });
```

I have a listview of objects when I select an object a new fragment is started, nothing fancy is done inside the fragment, just populates some information text boxes etc..

I've checked to see if it was possibly starting two fragments so I might need to back out twice to close and return to the previous fragment, but that is not the case.

I've also tried to override the onBackPressed method in my activity, and it is only called after the second back button is pressed, I am unsure what this means.  Any suggestions are welcome, it's probably something really simple that I'm just overlooking.

This is inside my MainActivity, it contains 3 fragments in the form of tabs, I'm dealing with tab3 at the moment, which contains the above listener for the listview.

```
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private SlidingTabLayout tabs;
private CharSequence Titles[] = {"Recent", "Library", "All"};
private int Numbtabs = 3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mViewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numbtabs);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);


    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width


    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(mViewPager);


}

//trying to solve double back button to exit objfragment
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
    else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

***Answered:*** I had a searchview in Fragment A that still had focus behind Fragment B, so the first backpress was clearing that focus, letting the second backpress do what I thought it should. Thank you for your help, I apologize the information I posted originally wasn't sufficient in helping me find a solution to my problem.

Comment: post code of back click.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can do something like this in your code

//Click of the Item
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long arg3) {
            final Obj item = (obj) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putParcelable("obj", item);
            Fragment fragment = new ObjFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(b);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fragment).addToBackStack("ObjFragment").commit();
        }
    });

//Backpress code
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    try {
                        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: I added what you suggested to my onBackPressed() in my activity that owns the fragment.  The functionality didn't change, and the first backpress call didn't trigger an exception.

Comment: Correct, the above listener is inside of a fragment (Fragment A), when an object is selected a new fragment is brought up with the objects information (Fragment B).  I want to return to Fragment A after hitting backpress in Fragment B.  Which does work, I'm just trying to figure out why it initially requires two backpresses.

Comment: where are you calling backpress code, inside your activity??

Comment: I'm calling it in my MainActivity where Fragment A is initially setup.  From what I understand I can't override onBackPress() inside of a fragment so I would need to do so from the activity?  Or am I mistaken in thinking this?

Comment: yes, you have to override onBackPressed inside your activity. I did the sam way and its working for me. May be your are doing something else inside your code. you can debug it check it

Answer (score 0):

Answered: I had a searchview in Fragment A that still had focus behind Fragment B, so the first backpress was clearing that focus, letting the second backpress do what I thought it should. Thank you for your help, I apologize the information I posted originally wasn't sufficient in helping me find a solution to my problem.